# Ruby-ODBC transaction statement not updating table in MSSQL (Mac OSX)

Tags: sql-server, ruby, macos, freetds, unixodbc

I have successfully installed FreeTDS (1.00.15) with unixODBC (2.3.4) and accessed MS SQL Server (2014). I was able to verify that the issue I am currently having doesn't lie with FreeTDS and unixODBC. This is because from within isql client prompt, I am able to execute both select and update queries.

I am running El Capitan OS X with the Sinatra app which has the ruby-odbc gem, a requirement.

The application is able to query records from the database properly. However, when I try running a ruby method which triggers an update statement, in the logs it says it's successful, but when I check the database nothing has been updated. This is hindering the ruby web app from updating the data source correctly.

**New Information**

So what I discovered this morning (11-11-2016) is that ruby-odbc doesn't work if the update statement is ran in a transaction block. However, if I comment out the transaction, it works perfectly fine and commits the data. This is the difference in the processing of the code between OS X and Fedora.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Comment: I should mention that this application is already running correctly in Fedora 23 fine. I am trying to run this application natively in OSX without changing the application itself and breaking it for the owners of this app.

Answer (score 1):

If it is anything like using `FreeTDS` with `Python` or `PHP`, you're going to have to set `autocommit=True` as part of your connection options. Search here for `autocommit` for more details:

http://www.ch-werner.de/rubyodbc/odbc.html

Good luck!

Comment: I should mention that this application is already running correctly in Fedora 23 fine. I am trying to run this application natively in OSX without changing the application itself.